# Store request answer in a variable

Tags: javascript, api, request

new to JavaSript i'm currently working on a discord bot using an API. And I would like to know how I could store the request answers in some variables so I can use them later to write on a .json file.

API used : https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/account
(I can show the answer with a console.log without problems but I cant store them :/ )

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix+"add")){
    const fs = require('fs') //importing file save
    var fPath = './data.json'
    var fRead = fs.readFileSync(fPath);
    var fFile = JSON.parse(fRead); //ready for use
    var userId = message.author.id //user id here
    var n; var g;
    if (!fFile[userId]) { //this checks if data for the user has already been created
        cut=message.content.replace("?add ", "");
        api.authenticate(cut).account().blob().then(request=> n=(request.account.name))
        api.authenticate(cut).account().blob().then(request=> g=(request.account.guilds)); 

        fFile[userId] = {key: cut, uidgw2:n, guild: g, role:""} //if not, create it
        fs.writeFileSync(fPath, JSON.stringify(fFile, null, 2));
    } else {
        message.reply("Déjà dans la base.");
        console.log(message.author.id+" déjà dans data.json");
}
  }
})
```

My problem is that n & g are apparently undefined and so i get that in my .json file :

```
{
  "231452514608360960": {
    "key": "B1257308-125X-8040-A55B-0AD1CF03480DF08F4AC2-9326-44DC-83A6-75A950C5ADFA",
    "role": ""
  }
}
```

Even if I declare them outside bot.on or inside, still undefined and I dont have much knowledge in js & api requests...

Comment: Hiho. How can you not store it on a variable ? Do you have a snippet of the code that is not working?

Comment: When you `console.log` this `request.account.name` does it have data or also undefined? Also since in your `.json` file there isn't even a key with `uidgw2` in it, does it even run the `if` block or just the `else` block?

Comment: @Trijoikolip see my updated answer. it should solve your problem

Comment: btw, why are you initiating two calls to: api.authenticate(cut).account().blob() ? Cant you do one and get both name and guilds at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: based on the further explanation added to the original question:

You have to remember that the promises from the API calls are resolved after the initial pass. yet you try and use the values already in the first pass.

Something like this should work:

```
Promise.all([api.authenticate(cut).account().blob(), 
             api.authenticate(cut).account().blob()])
           .then((requests) => {
                n = requests[0].account.name;
                g = requests[1].account.guilds;

                fFile[userId] = {key: cut, uidgw2:n, guild: g, role:""} //if not, create it
               fs.writeFileSync(fPath, JSON.stringify(fFile, null, 2));
            });
});
```

---

You havent shown what is failing here but if I were to guess Id say your issue has to do with the fact youre declaring 'n' and 'g' both outside the message callback and inside.

you have

```
 var n; var g;
```

inside the callback but also at the first two lines.

if you remove the declaration inside the callback you will be able to access the values outside.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, I'll edit my main message to show my problem.

Comment: I'll try thid when back home (30min), thanks for helping